# Check if array contains elements

Tags: java, arrays

If you have one empty example like `current[x] = 0` (assuming you know x)

If you are getting a lot of numbers, for example:

```
123
231
231
```

I edited those numbers so each time i get the number it's converted to an array like:

```
new[0] = 1
new[1] = 2
new[2] = 3
```

How can I add those numbers to current array like this:

```
current[0] = 1
current[1] = 2
current[2] = 3
```

but now, the 2nd new array should **not** repeat same numbers (idk how to explain with words so here is picture:

[image]

so if you add numbers like at the picture, you would get this at the end:

```
current[0] = 1
current[1] = 2
current[2] = 3
current[3] = 1
current[4] = 3
current[5] = 2
current[6] = 1
```

Maybe arrays are wrong way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You appears to have sequences of digits.  Is there any reason 123 is not stored as `123` I suggest using a set and this is designed to detect/ignore duplicates.

Comment: `HashSet` is your friend.

Comment: Did any of the solutions worked ? If yes then please accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rephrase the problem:
You have 2 lists and you have to concatenate those list in this way:

```
newList = firstList.someHead() + firstList.someTail() + secondList.someTail()
```

with the condition:

```
firstList.someTail() == secondList.someHead()
```

or

```
newList = firstList if firstList.contains(secondList)
```

So you have to iterate through both lists and find the complete match e.g one of the itarators has no next

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use a string variable as your final results. Whenever a new number comes in start by checking the existence using contains() function. The remove digits from the incoming number one-by-one and checking with contains(). The moment you have a hit add the removed digits at the end of your final string.

```
String strFinal = "";
String arrNo = "123";
String removedDigits = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrNo.length() ; i++){
if(strFinal.contains(arrNo))
break;
else
{
removedDigits = arrNo.subString(arrNo.length() -2) + removedDigits; // removedDigits = 3, 23, 123
arrNo = arrNo.subString(0, arrNo.length() - 1); // arrNo = 12, 1, ""
}
}
strFinal += removedDigits; //123
```